# How to group a table by date and company id in C# and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have this table :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[lcr_LogLastAccess] 
(
    [Id]                  INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [logl_Company]        VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [logl_Name]           VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [logl_Login]          VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [logl_AccessdDate]    DATETIME     NULL,
    [logl_Host]           VARCHAR(150) NULL,
    [logl_Browser]        VARCHAR(100) NULL,
    [logl_VersionBrowser] VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [logl_Platform]       VARCHAR(50)  NULL,
    [logl_CreatedOn]      DATETIME     NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_LogLastAccess] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

With this data :

```
id  logl_company  logl_AccessdDate
----------------------------------
1    carrefour    22/12/20 19:00
2    express      22/12/20 18:00
3    carrefour    22/12/20 17:00
4    express      22/12/20 16:00
5    mendes       22/12/20 15:00
```

I need to print this :

```
Carrefour    22/12/20 19:00
Express      22/12/20 18:00
Mendes       22/12/20 15:00
```

So, I need to group (`logl_Company`) by recent accessed date (`logl_AccessdDate`)

What I have tried and feel I'm stuck at:

```
using (var db = new AcessoContext()) 
{
    // var maxSample = db.lcr_LogLastAccess
    //    .Where(coluna => coluna.logl_AccessdDate == db.lcr_LogLastAccess.Max(coluna => coluna.logl_AccessdDate))     //Pega a maior data e retornar em string
    //    .First();
    // grupos.SelectMany(a => a.Where(b => b.logl_AccessdDate == a.Max(c => c.logl_AccessdDate)));

    var lista = new List<AcessoModel>();

    var grupos = db.lcr_LogLastAccess.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(coluna => coluna.logl_Company);

    foreach (var empresa in grupos)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(empresa);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(lista.Count() + "\n");
    Console.ReadLine();

    // PARA CADA EMPRESA NA COMPANY IMPRIMIR A LINHA INTEIRA QUE A DATA SEJA MAIS RECENTE      
}
```

My count says that my list is empty .. and my foreach returns

```
System.Linq.Grouping`2[System.String,CONSOLE_TESTE2.AcessoModel]
```

How to solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: 1) `lista` is always going to be empty because you never add anything into it. 2) Why are you using `AsEnumerable()`? It's breaking EF's ability to smartly query the database. 3) `empresa` is an object, so it's trying to print information for the object. You need to format that into a table.

Comment: Hi gunr , i used AsEnumerable() because it was giving one Exception that said i needed to call AsNumerable() before the groupby.

Answer (score 3):

Use below `LINQ` to get the result -

```
var grupos = db.lcr_LogLastAccess.GroupBy(g => g.logl_Company).Select(s => new
        {
            logl_Company = s.Key,
            logl_AccessdDate = s.Max(m => m.logl_AccessdDate)
        }).ToList();
```